# Keymap causes Readline Delay on `.` in Vi Mode

Tags: bash, vi, readline

When I press `.` in Vi/command mode there is always a delay (half a second) before the last action gets repeated.

I found that this is caused by my `.inputrc`:

```
set editing-mode vi
set keymap vi-command
"d-": kill-line
```

Why is the `"d-"` mapping causing this delay?

---

Repro:

- In Bash insert mode enter `foo bar foobar`
- press `esc`, type `0`
- enter `dw` to delete foo
- press `.` to delete bar (there is a delay)
- press `.` to delete foobar (there is a delay)

Comment: What is the output of `bind -psvX | grep -F .`?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski it says ".": vi-redo. I found it's caused by a keymapping (updated)